# How to avoid implicit collection resolving in Autofac?

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, autofac, resolve

I'm implementing MVP pattern in ASP.NET and I have defined a view like below:

```
public interface IMyView
    {
         IList<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MyPage : Page, IMyView
    {
        public IList<User> Users
        {
            set
            {
                this.grid.DataSource = value;
                this.grid.DataBound();
            }
        }
```

My sample page inherits from the view but whenever I visit the page Autofac assigns a default empty value to Users property and DataBound throws an exception because my page is not built completely yet.
How can I configure Autofac to not to resolve it automatically?
The only thing I can do now is to change IList to List.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to modify your registration and not to use property injection for this type, this is the solution I recommend.

By the way, if you can't change the registration mode, I can see 3 solutions.

1. Change the way the property works by using a state.

   ```
   public MyPage: Page, IMyView
   {

     private Boolean _isInitialized; 


     public void Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       this._isInitialized = true; 
     }


     public IList<User> Users
     {
       get { ... }
       set
       {
         if (this._isInitialized) 
         {
           this.grid.DataSource = value;
           this.grid.DataBound();
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Dirty but simple to implement.
2. Implement your own `PropertiesAutoWiring`. You can do so by using the OnActivating event.

   ```
   ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

   builder.RegisterType<MyPage>().OnActivating(e =>
   {
       foreach (PropertyInfo pi in e.Instance.GetType()
                                               .GetProperties()
                                               .Where(pi => pi.CanWrite))
       {
           if (!pi.PropertyType.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IList<>)))
           {
               Object propertyValue = e.Context.ResolveOptional(pi.PropertyType);
               if (propertyValue != null)
               {
                   pi.SetValue(e.Instance, propertyValue);
               }
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   Don't use this code, it is just to get you the iead. Look at [AutowiringPropertyInjector.cs](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/c9b56b7737df387afa667a6833b9d6100f6100be/src/Autofac/Core/Activators/Reflection/AutowiringPropertyInjector.cs) for a good implementation of this code.
3. Remove the collection support in *Autofac*. Collection support is managed by the [`CollectionRegistrationSource`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/c9b56b7737df387afa667a6833b9d6100f6100be/src/Autofac/Features/Collections/CollectionRegistrationSource.cs). Unfortunately There is no way to tell *Autofac* to remove only the collection support, you can only remove all default adapters.

   ```
   IContainer container = builder.Build(ContainerBuildOptions.ExcludeDefaultModules);
   ```

   This will remove all default modules, ie :

   ```
   private void RegisterDefaultAdapters(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry)
   {
     this.RegisterGeneric(typeof(KeyedServiceIndex<, >)).As(new Type[]
     {
       typeof(IIndex<, >)
     }).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
     componentRegistry.AddRegistrationSource(new CollectionRegistrationSource());
     componentRegistry.AddRegistrationSource(new OwnedInstanceRegistrationSource());
     componentRegistry.AddRegistrationSource(new MetaRegistrationSource());
     componentRegistry.AddRegistrationSource(new LazyRegistrationSource());
     componentRegistry.AddRegistrationSource(new LazyWithMetadataRegistrationSource());
     componentRegistry.AddRegistrationSource(new StronglyTypedMetaRegistrationSource());
     componentRegistry.AddRegistrationSource(new GeneratedFactoryRegistrationSource());
   }
   ```

Unfortunately, when `PropertiesAutoWired()` is used, there is no way to tell *Autofac* not to inject a specific property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I'm not using PropertiesAutoWired and even I have not registered my view in Autofac.

Comment: @alirezam *Autofac* try to set property in your types so, something is registering your types with `PropertiesAutowiring`. Edit your question and include how you configure *Autofac* there may have a solution for you there.

Comment: I double checked I haven't used at all PropertiesAutowiring property.In previous version of Autofac I didn't have this problem after upgrading to Autofac v3 the problem occurs.

Comment: @alirezam How do you configure *Autofac* something else may use `PropertiesAutowiring` internally. Could you use a breakpoint and look at the call stack to see who call the setter ?

Comment: For information [Autofac 3.1.3](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Release-Notes#313) introduce support for `IList<T>`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
Thanks to your answer it helped me to find the cause.
After upgrading to version Autofac version 3 I have following module in web config:

```
<add name="PropertyInjection" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.PropertyInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

So I need to remove it and replace it with following:

```
 <add
        name="AttributedInjection"
        type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.AttributedInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler" />
```